# How to make Checkbox=TRUE if SUM of cells in its row are more than a specific value

Tags: google-sheets

I have a row of numbers and those in columns C through F are added together in G. I want H to be a checkbox that is TRUE if the SUM in G is greater than 29. I think I use the SUMIF formula but couldn't figure out the Checkbox part. Thanks for your help and patience with this beginner question!

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data are from `G4` to `G17`

**3 Steps**

1. Click on cell `H4` and place the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(G4:G17>20,TRUE,FALSE))
```

You will get a list of `FALSE`, `TRUE` depending on your `G` column values.

2. Select the cells `H4:H17`
3. Go to top menu `Insert` > `Tickbox`

[image: change Checkbox to TRUE depending on another cell's value]